# Input field with increment and decrement button

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have an input box which also has two arrows (up and down) to increment or decrement it's value.

The HTML are

```
<span class="k-numeric-wrap k-state-default k-state-hover">
<input class="k-formatted-value k-input valid" type="text" tabindex="0" style="display: inline;" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"/>
<input id="DisplayOrder" class="k-input valid" type="text" value="0" name="DisplayOrder" data-val-required="'Display Order' must not be empty." data-val-number="The field Display order must be a number." data-val="true" data-role="numerictextbox" role="spinbutton" style="display: none;" aria-valuenow="1" aria-disabled="false" aria-readonly="false"/>
<span class="k-select">
<span class="k-link" unselectable="on">

<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-n" title="Increase value" unselectable="on">Increase value</span>
</span>
<span class="k-link" unselectable="on">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" title="Decrease value" unselectable="on">Decrease value</span>
</span>
```

Now, I am trying to clear this input field first, then try to enter the value 1 and finally use the increment button to increment the value of 1 to 2.

My code is

```
@FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='k-numeric-wrap k-state-default']") WebElement Category_Display_Order;
@FindBy(xpath="//span[@class='k-link']//span[@title='Increase value']") WebElement Category_Increase_Value;

Category_Display_Order.clear();
Category_Display_Order.sendKeys("1");
Category_Increase_Value.click();
```

but upon doing so - I get the error

org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 10.03 seconds

Comment: Can you try to put some explicit waits on the element throwing the notvisibleexeption, before you access it.

Comment: In which line have you got this error??

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `sendKeys()` on wrong element, that's why you are in trouble. You should try as below :-

```
@FindBy(id ="DisplayOrder") 
WebElement Category_Display_Order;

@FindBy(css ="span[title='Increase value']") 
WebElement Category_Increase_Value;

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Category_Display_Order));

Category_Display_Order.clear();
Category_Display_Order.sendKeys("1");

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Category_Increase_Value)).click();
```

Comment: Tried the below changes as suggested by you but still see issues

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Category_Display_Order));
Category_Display_Order.clear();
System.out.println("Input Field cleared");
Category_Display_Order.sendKeys("20");
System.out.println("Input 20 entered");
  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Category_Increase_Value));
Category_Increase_Value.click();
System.out.println("Value incremented");

Comment: Result

Issue 1 - The input field Category_Display_Order has a pre-populated value 0 which does not get cleared.
Issue 2 - So 20 is getting added as "200"

Eclipse result:

Input Field cleared
Input 20 entered
FAILED: validate_login
org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of 
[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on WINDOWS (10a3fb59-affd-47ae-97b4-318ca3cc453a)] -> xpath: //span[@title='Increase value']]
Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'

Comment: I don't think why it's not visible after given time, you should try using `JavascriptExecutor` then to perform click action as `((JavascriptExecutor)driver.executeScript("arguments[0].click()",Category_Increase_Value)`

Comment: no error this time but click did not increment the value.
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].click()", Category_Increase_Value);
 Thread.sleep(5000);
 System.out.println("Value incremented");

Comment: That means you're locating incorrect element, need to verify your locator..

Answer (score 0):

I found that your xpath selectors are not correct.

Try these element reference selectors:

```
@FindBy(xpath="//input[@class='k-formatted-value k-input valid']") 
WebElement Category_Display_Order;

@FindBy(xpath="//span[@title='Increase value']") 
WebElement Category_Increase_Value;
```

and let me know if the problem is solved.